# Select, where id = multiple from other select

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-tables

I'm tired and I can't wrap my head around this. I have two tables:

```
table menu
@id = id, @nr = id of parent
|======|======|  
|  id  |  nr  |
|======|======|
|  10  |   9  |
|  11  |  10  |
|  12  |  10  |
|  13  |  10  |
|======|======|

table content
@id = id, @mf = menu - first in tree, @mi = menu item linked to content
|======|======|======|
|  id  |  mf  |  mi  |
|======|======|======|
|  85  |   9  |  11  |
|  89  |   9  |  12  |
|  95  |   9  |  13  |
|======|======|======|
```

Now, I need to select all rows from `content`, where (`mi` = `menu`.`id`), but i need to select `menu`.`id` from `menu` first by selecting `*` from `menu` where `nr` = 10 (or any number, which I put to my sql with PHP)

I really can't wrap my head around all those UNIONS, LEFT JOINS, HAVING and stuff...

Thank you

**Edit:** *Thank you ALL, shame I can pick just one good :)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're asking for? The following will return all rows in content where mi is in menu.id and nr=10.

```
select *
from content
where mi in (select id from menu where nr=10)
```

Comment: @Winston, he was first, tried to help and needs reputation more than you do :D Although, thank you for your solution also, got upvoted - and we talk about site with +/- 500 hits per day with the inner select with max 35 items, so efficiency is not thing here :]

Comment: @Adam - While it might not be important **this** time, but perhaps it's helpful to understand the differences in both solutions so that you have a wider range of tools at your disposal *next* time.

Comment: A good optimizer should (in theory) be able to turn a subquery like this into a join, but I don't think MySQL can.  You can check with EXPLAIN.

Comment: @Winston - that's why **this** time i picked Aaron's answer as good... and when I'll understand the thing more, I'll appreciate your solution :)

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT C.* FROM content C
INNER JOIN menu ON C.mi = menu.id AND menu.nr = 10;
```

**UPDATE:**

In response to your comment, you might find the [W3 Schools section on SQL JOINS](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join.asp) a helpful resource to get started with.

Comment: Thank you, although I picked simpler looking answer, I will look into your response, try to understand it and learn from it :]

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM content WHERE mi IN(SELECT id FROM menu WHERE nr = 10)

Answer (score 0):

untested

SELECT content.* FROM content, menu WHERE menu.nr = 10 AND content.mi = menu.id

or

SELECT c.*, menu.nr FROM menu LEFT JOIN content AS c ON menu.id = c.mi WHERE menu.nr = 10